# ViewPager calls onPause() onResume()

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, onresume, onpause

When I using `ViewPager` with fragments   `onPause()`, `onResume()` methods are called when moving to tabs which are far from the one more than 1 tabs.

I want to save all the fragments data so don't want to call  `onPause()`, `onResume()` in the `Activity`.

How can I stop calling those functions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `viewPager` only keep in memory one fragment in each side.. is like this:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

You can increase that number, but be careful, you can easily run out of memory..